# how to prevent redundant text being read in screen reader?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

This is my first time tackling accessibility. I am using talkback on my phone to test accessibility of items. The issue I have is that if I have content in an anchor, it reads the entire thing once and then when you swipe it reads the individual text inside the anchor. Here's the code I have:

```
<ul>
    <li class="relatedFeatured">
        <a href="https://www.weather.com/" target="_blank" aria-labelledby="relatedLinks">
            <div class="icon featuredIcon" aria-hidden="true">&#57409</div>
            <div class="relatedFeaturedText" id="relatedLinks">
                <strong>See the weather</strong>
                <p>Visit and find information on the climate in your area.</p>
            </div>
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">&#58124</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried adding role=text like so,

```
<ul>
    <li class="relatedFeatured">
        <a href="https://www.weather.com/" target="_blank" aria-labelledby="relatedLinks">
            <div class="icon featuredIcon" aria-hidden="true">&#57409</div>
            <div class="relatedFeaturedText" id="relatedLinks" role="text">
                <strong>See the weather</strong>
                <p>Visit and find information on the climate in your area.</p>
            </div>
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">&#58124</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, it still reads the items individually inside. The only other way I can think of is adding aria-hidden to that div, but not sure that is the proper way to go. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I need to correct?

Comment: remove `aria-labelledby`, the text will be read out that is within the link and you have correctly hidden the icons. It will probably fix the issue as well. `role="text"` isn't that useful yet except for fixing certain edge cases in iOS text splitting, it isn't technically rolled out yet so most screen readers ignore it. Use it sparingly (you often want `role="presentation none"` if you are trying to remove semantics etc.)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I removed the `aria-labelledby`, and I was still able to swipe through the individual text elements. Then I changed the role to presentation and then to none, and that still swiped to the individual text elements. This is happening on Chrome mobile. However it's behaving properly in FireFox mobile.

Comment: It's one of those "that's how the platform implemented it" kind of annoyances. I know iOS will split a link into parts as you swipe if there are blocking elements (such as `<div>`s) as child nodes of the link. Sounds like android is doing that too, unfortunately. `role="text"` is an undocumented way to fix iOS. I'm not aware that android would honor it. It doesn't feel right to leave it as is but it's really android's problem that it's working that way.

Comment: Just looked at your `role="text"` option again. You might need it set on a container higher up since the link already has a `<div>` (blocking element) before it encounters the text role (even though the first div is `aria-hidden`).  Try adding a `<div role="text">` as the first (and only) child of the `<a>` then put the rest of your code in the new `<div>`.  

Or you can try changing all your divs to spans to see if non-blocking elements fix the problem.  Non-blocking (span) works on iOS.

Comment: @slugolicious I tried using a single div with the role and placing all the content in there and changed the divs to spans, and both did not work. It works fine in iOS and works on FF - android. For some reason Chrome - android is being picky. The only way I can resolve it is if I set the aria-hidden to the text div, but not sure that would be proper.

Comment: As far as I know, you aren't supposed to have block-level elements like `<div>` inside `<a>`. Maybe you can divide your link into multiple ones. Some recent screen readers filter out consecutive identical links.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie From the answer below, your solution did work, it's just I had to remove the `role="text"` from the div and add `role="presentation"` to the child elements. I thought that changing from text to presentation would apply to all the child elements in the div, but that didn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following using Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy S10 with TalkBack (Android 11):

```
<ul>
    <li class="relatedFeatured">
        <a href="https://www.weather.com/" target="_blank">
            <div class="icon featuredIcon" aria-hidden="true">&#57409</div>
            <div class="relatedFeaturedText" id="relatedLinks">
                <strong role="presentation">See the weather</strong>
                <p role="presentation">Visit and find information on the climate in your area.</p>
            </div>
            <span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">&#58124</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, by using `role="presentation"` on the `<strong>` and `<p>` tags, TalkBack only reads the text inside the `<a>` tag, and not as individual text items. I also removed the `aria-labelledby` attribute as it's redundant, given that the text inside the `<a>` tag is already picke up by screen readers.

Comment: Okay now that works. Previously a commenter suggested `role="presentation"`, but I only replaced it where I had `role="text"` in the div. I thought that if I set it in the parent element that it would automatically apply to all the children elements.

Comment: No, `role="presentation"` (or `role="none"`) only applies to the tag it is assigned to. Other ARIA attributes, such as `aria-hidden="true"`, will affect all descendant elements.