# How can I make VoiceOver combine multiple span elements into one read item?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

I have the below HTML where part of the text is colored red. This is to visually draw attention to the text.

```
<div>
    <span style="color:red">Note: </span>
    <span>Don't forget your appointment.</span>
</div>
```

When I swipe right through this using VoiceOver it's read as:

*swipe* note

*swipe* don't forget your appointment

However, it doesn't make sense to make someone swipe twice to hear this message.

What I want is for this text to be read as a single element by Voiceover, the same as if the HTML was:

```
<div>
    Note: Don't forget your appointment.
</div>
```

Other styles, such as bolding a word in the middle of a sentence, also cause this issue.

Comment: Maybe using `role="presentation"` on each of the `<span>` elements, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69447452/20896315

Comment: Tried that just now, adding role="presentation" to the element with the color style. Same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out one possible solution. The way to fix this is to add the non-standard text role:

```
<div role="text">
    <span style="color:red">Note: </span>
    <span>Don't forget your appointment.</span>
</div>
```

This is, apparently, only recognized by iOS. However, I found that Android's TalkBack doesn't have this issue to begin with. It knows to read the line as a single item.

CAREFUL: this will also read across embedded links so they can't be activated.

For certain parent elements, this isn't necessary. For example, if the parent div is a button or has role="button" then it will read the inside as a single line. Same for an href parent.

Comment: See also slugolicious' answer for more context.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you have a formatting change between <span> elements or just a series of <span> elements, Apple decided that VoiceOver (VO) should stop at each DOM element. I can kind of see their point. It would be difficult to know when VO should stop at each <span> or when it should read them all together.

This used to be a problem when you had multiple <span> elements inside of a link but they have since fixed that.

```
<a href="example.com">
  <span style="color:red">Note: </span>
  <span>Don't forget your appointment.</span>
</a>
```

The above used to read out as two links because VO would stop at each <span> and would say:

- *"Note, link"*
- *"Don't forget your appointment, link"*

You can see how this might be confusing. Are there really two links?  No, but that's what it sounds like.  So Apple fixed that and announces it as one link now.

But they did not change how a <span> is handled in a <div> like your example. It might be important for the user to know they're separate DOM elements.

```
<div>
  <span style="color:red">Note: </span>
  <span>Don't forget your appointment.</span>
</div>
```

The only solution is, as you noted, is using the **undocumented** `text` role.  Only webkit browsers honor it and it has no affect in other browsers. Keep in mind that since it's undocumented and not officially supported by W3C ARIA, Apple *could* take it away at any point.  However, I have used it sparingly for over 10 years and it hasn't disappeared yet.

```
<div role="text">
  <span style="color:red">Note: </span>
  <span>Don't forget your appointment.</span>
</div>
```

As an interesting side note, the `text` role was considered at one point to be part of the [official ARIA spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) but it never got approval. You can see a discussion on the [W3C archives](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/wai-xtech/2011Apr/) from back in April 2011. The archives are sorted from newest at the top so you have to go to the bottom of that page to find the start of the discussion and look for *"suggestions for new roles and properties in ARIA next"*.  You can then read all the "RE:" responses.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! I love the thorough answer and history lesson :)

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing accessible about your html.
To make this accessible firstly use semantic html - ie html elements that describe their function, like p for paragraph, or h1 - h6 for heading and so on.

**example.html**

```html
<h4>Note:</h4>
<p>Don't forget your appointment.</p>
```

You can use styles to make it more visually appealing for most users, but visually impaired users may not see the colour, especially if they are using a screen reader.