# How to define an element as being normal text rather than a heading? (Accessibility reports are marking these elements as headings)

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

The H1 headings of our website have each word animated in separately. To accomplish this our script separates the words and spaces into individual `<span>` elements and styles/animates them accordingly.

The issue is that accessibility checkers are interpreting each word as a title, I'm assuming due to the styling that's applied to each one. I don't think this is an issue for actual users with assistive needs, but we like to provide passing accessibility reports to our clients and this is lowering the score significantly.

I added `role="presentation"` to each `span` element, thinking that should define these spans as not being headings, but it's not making a difference in the accessibility reports. Is there another attribute or property that's more fitting for this?

HTML:

```
<h1>
    <span class="word-wrap" role="presentation"><span class="word" role="presentation" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 0; --line-index: 0;">Heading</span></span>
    <span class="whitespace" role="presentation"> </span>
    <span class="word-wrap" role="presentation"><span class="word" role="presentation" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 1; --line-index: 0;">Text</span></span>
    <span class="whitespace" role="presentation"> </span>
    <span class="word-wrap" role="presentation"><span class="word" role="presentation" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 2; --line-index: 0;">Here</span></span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.word {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translate(0, 120%);
    transition: .8s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything inside an <h1> (or h2, h3, etc) is part of the heading. You can't make it *not* a heading unless it's outside of the <h1>.

A <span> element is already a [generic element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-span) and doesn't have a role so adding `role="presentation"` won't do anything. It's already a presentation role.

> accessibility checkers are interpreting each word as a **title**,

What scanning tool are you using (axe, wave, lighthouse, siteimprove, etc) and what's the error it's generating? And by "interpreting each word as a **title**", I assume you mean "interpreting each word as a **heading**"?  If so, that's not an error and I don't know any scanning tools that would even mention that.

Your HTML is perfectly valid. Both from an [HTML spec perspective](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) and from an accessibility perspective (*). The heading element is pretty liberal on what's alowed inside it.  You're allowed to have "[phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)", which is about 5 dozen different elements, including <span> elements.

(*) From an accessibility perspective, you mentioned the heading text is animated. That *might* be a problem if the animation starts automatically (without a user interaction) and lasts longer than 5 seconds and there's no way for the user to stop the animation. It would be a [WCAG 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#pause-stop-hide) issue.

However, as currently written, the code works ok (**). Using the NVDA screen reader, when I navigate to the heading using the <kbd>H</kbd> shortcut key, NVDA says, *"Heading      Text      Here,      heading    level 1"*. If I use the <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to navigate each DOM element, NVDA says, *"heading    level 1,  Heading      Text      Here    "*.  It's ok that "heading level 1" is announced before or after the actual text.

(**) On iOS (and maybe the Mac) with VoiceOver, when you swipe right or if you change your rotor to navigate by "Headings", you will stop on each <span> element and each one will be announced as a heading. That's just how VoiceOver works. You could work around that issue by using **undocumented** `role="text"` but read my comments regarding that role here, [How can I make VoiceOver combine multiple span elements into one read item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325133/how-can-i-make-voiceover-combine-multiple-span-elements-into-one-read-item/76333554#76333554) .  You just need a parent <span> around your other <span>s with the "text" role.

```
<h1>
  <span role="text">
    <span class="word-wrap">
      <span class="word" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 0; --line-index: 0;">Heading</span>
    </span>
    <span class="whitespace"></span>
    <span class="word-wrap">
      <span class="word" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 1; --line-index: 0;">Text</span>
    </span>
    <span class="whitespace"></span>
    <span class="word-wrap">
      <span class="word" data-delay="0" style="--word-index: 2; --line-index: 0;">Here</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that incredibly detailed and insightful response! The main scanning tool we use is accessiBe, and that's giving the failure on the span tags with the message: `Titles built as text tags should be labeled as headings for assistive technology`. I assumed this wouldn't actually be an issue, but like I said it would be nice to generate a clean report. The animations for each word are only about .2 seconds. I'm going to try `role="text"` and see if that helps, but if not I guess we'll just have to explain to the client the scanner is wrong in this case. Thanks again!

Comment: `role="text"` will only help with VoiceOver navigation on iOS (and maybe Mac). It will not affect the heading. I've never seen that scanning error. I've heard of accessibe, and honestly, it doesn't have a good reputation. I don't agree with the error message, nor is it very clear. What "titles"? There aren't any `title` attributes on your elements. What do they mean by "text tags"? There is no <t> element. I've been doing accessibility reviews for 20 years so I'm quite familiar with most scanning tools and the errors they generate. Contact me offline (profile) if you want accessibe articles.